# Why Ambiguous use of 'identifier' show when print object of NSMutableArray in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I an developing in Swift and BLE. I scan the BLE device and add them to a NSMutableArray. When I try to print the all object in NSMutableArray , it show **Ambiguous use of 'identifier'**

I add the device at scan callback like the following code:

```
var ScanMeshList:NSMutableArray?

        func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {

                print("peripheral name = \(peripheral.name)")
                print("peripheral id = \(peripheral.identifier)")
                print("peripheral rssi = \(RSSI)")

                ScanMeshList?.addObject(peripheral)

            }
```

And print the all object in the NSMutableArray when click the button:

```
@IBAction func StopScan(sender: AnyObject) {
        //for device in ScanMeshList!
        for var index = 0; index < ScanMeshList!.count; index++
        {
            print("ScanMeshList device name = \(ScanMeshList![index].name) , id = \(ScanMeshList![index].identifier)")
        }
    }
```

But it show the error(**Ambiguous use of 'identifier'**) at `print("ScanMeshList device name = \(ScanMeshList![index].name) , id = \(ScanMeshList![index].identifier)")`

Did I missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things here. The problem is probably coming from the fact that the compiler doesn't know what ScanMeshList contains. Since you are putting it in an NSMutableArray, there is no type information along with it.

If you want to use it in its current state, you would need to cast your objects in your for loop. Example Below:

```
print("ScanMeshList device name = \((ScanMeshList![index] as! CBCBPeripheral).name) , id = \((ScanMeshList![index] as! CBCBPeripheral).identifier)")
```

However i would strongly suggest taking advantage of swifts generics and add the CBPeripheral objects to a swift typed array, this way the compiler knows the type of each object in the array and avoids any casting. Example below:

```
var scanMeshList:[CBPeripheral] = [CBPeripheral]()

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {

    print("peripheral name = \(peripheral.name)")
    print("peripheral id = \(peripheral.identifier)")
    print("peripheral rssi = \(RSSI)")

    scanMeshList.append(peripheral)
}

func StopScan(sender: AnyObject) {
    //for device in scanMeshList!
    for (scanMeshListItem) in scanMeshList {
        print("ScanMeshList device name = \(scanMeshListItem.name) , id = \(scanMeshListItem.identifier)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the array element to the expected type `CGPeripheral`. Swift doesn't know what type the elements of the array are.

```
if let thePeripheral = ScanMeshList![index] as? CBPeripheral {
    print("ScanMeshList device name = \(thePeripheral.name) , id = \(thePeripheral.identifier)")
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a typed Swift array `[CBPeripheral]` instead of an `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a native `Array`, `NSMutableArray` is to vague because is does not contain the type information.

```
var scanMeshList = [CBPeripheral]()
```

And there is no need to use an optional. If there is no device the array is empty.